# HAML How to define a method?

Tags: html, ruby, methods, haml

I have the following ruby method:

```
def dedup_uniq(array)
 {
   uniq: array.uniq,
   dup: array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }.select { |k,v| v > 1 }.keys
 }
end
```

How can i create the same method in `haml` code? Or how can i include this method in my haml doc?

Thank you.

Comment: are you using rails? if so why not just use a helper method?

Comment: i am using `.haml` doc, which is based on ruby. I don't know how to use a helper method, or if it works with `haml`. If you can explain, i would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Put that method in `app/helpers/something.rb`, and in the `haml` file, just write `= dedup_array([...])`.

Comment: However, it might be helpful for you to share *what you're actually trying to use that method for*, in the `haml` file. The looks like a possible XY problem to me.

Comment: as an answer to my previous question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52105788/haml-each-function-for-variables/52105961?noredirect=1#comment91163640_52105961), somebody showed me how to solve my issue with a new method. On that link things are better explained. Thank you.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Comment: There is no rush. It helped me solve my problem, so i selected his answer. If you have a better answer, please write it down.

Comment: I do not wish to post an answer. My comment was a general one.  I dislike quick-draw green checkmarks. They may discourage other answers and imo are discourteous to those still working on answers. There's no rush. Many here wait at least a couple of hours before making a selection.

Comment: Ok, i understand. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this if you have some standalone HAML files and you have no place to define the method elsewhere.

```
  -def dedup_uniq(array)
    -{ uniq: array.uniq, dup: array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }.select { |k,v| v > 1 }.keys }
```

Never do that in a Rails view, it's always better to define a helper.

Answer (score 0):

You should not define complex methods inside HAML, but instead use helper methods. As long as your HAML has access to your helper method you can just call it like this from your haml file:

```
= dedup_uniq([:some, :example, :array, :items])
```

But in your case your method is returning a hash, so not sure what you intend to do with that data in your view, but you'll have access to the object returned by the method.

Comment: ok, so i have my `.haml` doc where i have all my variables and my code that will be translated to html by haml. I don't know how to use helper methods, or where to add them. @Tom Lord said to put them in  `app/helpers/something.rb`, but i don't know where the app folder should be located. I looked into my ruby folder, and i don't have an app folder.

Comment: You may be wondering why I made such a trivial edit. It was because I had accidentally downvoted your answer and could not remove that downvote without you or someone else doing an edit. Sorry! btw, I know nothing of HAML, so cannot evaluate your answer anyway. I'll remove this comment when I figure you've seen it.

Comment: Ok. No problem. Thanks for letting me know. :)